# how can I set memory in hadoop-evn.sh

Tags: configuration, hadoop

How can I set memory in hadoop-env.sh?

```
# Extra Java runtime options
# export HADOOP_OPTS=-server
```

If I want to set NN:20G DN:4G, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set them in `hadoop-env.sh`.

```
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Xmx20G ... "
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Xmx4G ... "
```